# Android Java: How to get component in a custom view? (Trying to access components via findByViewId and get null)

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-components

Trying to access components via findByViewId and get null
The problem is in this line:

(I cannot connect my viewxml to the class)

```
// HERE I GET NULL
    **_addButton     = context.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);**
```

I have an activity:
with this OnCreate:

MainActivity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

I have a custom view I call in my MainActivity
MainActivity xml

```
   <com.example.myemptyapplication.PlayersFragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view_players"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"/>
```

In 'PlayersFragment' I' trying to access

```
PlayersFragment extends View
```

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public PlayersFragment(Context context, AttributeSet attSet) {
        super(context, attSet);
```

```
 protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    // HERE I GET NULL
        **_addButton     = context.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);**
    }
```

Tried to get components in a custom view

Comment: There is no sign of anything named `buttonAdd` in your question. Where is `buttonAdd` coming from?

Comment: What is context in your snippet? If it is Android context, then there is no findViewById method.

Comment: buttonAdd this commin from an XML:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Don't call views Fragments.  Fragments are a separate concept in Android, and your code will confuse everyone.

2)If you created that view as a subview of your custom view, you'd use findViewById, not context.findViewById.  Because the view isn't in the context, its one of your subviews.

Comment: Thanks! (2) this actually what what actually worked.

Comment: @TammyRoytvarf 1 wasn't a way to solve it , it was advice.  Calling them Fragments when Fragments are a separate major concept in Android confuses everyone who reads the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!!!
I've found a way to connect the xml to the View class:

```
ayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_players, null, false);
```